# SQL Find Nearest Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm looking to find the nearest number to 5 in the column row and order it so closest is at the top.

Here is what  I got....

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Technicians WHERE Zone=15 ORDER BY Zone DESC
```

Doing this in vb and getting error.

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: @marc_s - that's an Access error message.  I tagged it for that.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match the actual text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order a `numeric` column such that those at the top of the list are closest to `5`, you need a function to tell you how close a value is to 5.  `ABS(value - 5)` should do that for you.

This gives the following clause...

```
ORDER BY
  ABS(tableValue - 5) ASCENDING
```

Note, however, that your error message implies that your `Zone` field isn't numeric.  This means that you either need to cast the value to a numeric type, or change the field itself to be a numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

That's an **MS Access** error, and I'm guessing your `Zone` field is not actually numerical.

Try `WHERE Zone='15'`